# biblatex-sbl and Studia Patristica

Tags: biblatex-sbl

According to the [SBL Blog](https://sblhs2.com/2017/09/14/studia-patristica/), Studia Patristica has a special citation style. I have not seen this in the [examples](https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/blob/master/doc/biblatex-sbl-examples.pdf) for `biblatex-sbl`.

What is the correct `entrytype` for Studia Patristica? Should it be `article` as if it were a journal article? A full example (one from the above blog is fine) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use LaTeX macros in titles, author names etc. in a `.bib` file. In this case `\textup{}` can be used to print the volume name upright instead of in italics.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sblrefs.bib}
\begin{document}
See bibliography below \nocite{Husek,Tkacz}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

`sblrefs.bib`:

```
@article{Husek,
    title = {Human Freedom according to the Earliest Latin Commentaries on Paul's Letters},
    author = {Hušek, Vít},
    journal = {\textup{StPatr}},
    volume = {44},
    pages = {385--390},
    year = {2010}
}

@article{Tkacz,
    title = {Esther as a Type of Christ and the Jewish Celebration of Purim},
    author = {Brown Tkacz, Catherine},
    journal = {StPatr},
    volume = {44},
    pages = {183--187},
    year = {2010}
}
```

Note that only one of the entries has the `\textup` macro, to show the difference in output.

Result:

[image]

Note also that this is slightly different from the format on the website regarding punctuation and author names, but that is a different issue.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The reason for the difference in punctuation is because they are showing footnote examples. The punctuation in your example is correct in the footnotes as well. The one change I am making is to have a series bib entry with the shortseries StPatr, then to nocite it so that it shows up in the list of abbreviations with the correct roman type (not italics). If one uses shortjournal, the name will show up in italics in the abbreviation list, which is wrong.

Comment: Also, biblatex-sbl takes care of the dash length in the bibliography, so in the bib file you don't need to put two "--" in the pages; just one.